# Paypal - how to show order summary

Tags: paypal

I am trying to figure out how to show Order summary in Paypal express checkout. What I currently have is this:

[image]

what I am trying to get is this (**visible by default "order summary"**)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. PayPal has migrated the legacy pages (second screenshot you shared) to new pages (first screenshot).

Any reason that you want to display the cart information on page load?

Comment: UX reason mainly. when a person who is going to pay hits the PP landing page - he doesn't see what he is paying for.

Comment: ya it is not directly visible but buyer can click on cart icon see all the details of the cart. Cart total is always displayed in top right corner

Comment: yeah, I know. just wanted to have it visible ...well, thanks, man. take care